# Is scapy-ssl-tls work supported in Windows

Tags: scapy

I need to work with scapy-ssl-tls library through python program. I am a Windows user. I tried to find way to install it in Windows but coudl not find any reference including the library's Github page [here](https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls). Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1):

*Update:* nowadays there is a SSL/TLS implementation builtin scapy.

To install scapy-ssl-tls, there are two steps:

1. Install scapy: download it using pip `pip install scapy --pre` or via the github page: https://github.com/secdev/scapy
2. Download scapy-ssl-tls, and install it using the instructions here: https://github.com/tintinweb/scapy-ssl_tls#installation